# Angular how to fill an array from another array

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an array with called my games it has a lot of property such as game type i want to fill  some three ohter array based on the property game type but it did not work
this is an exemple of the array my gam

```
hideScore: true, started: true, startedAt: "Fri, 02 Jul 2021 09:04:25 GMT", finished: true, finishedAt: "Fri, 20 Aug 2021 15:35:37 GMT", …}
archived: false
bgGame: "#1a1f29"
client: "client test"
company: "tunisia"
country: "Tunisia"
createdAt: "2021-07-02T09:03:34.015Z"
finished: true
finishedAt: "Fri, 20 Aug 2021 15:35:37 GMT"
gameType: "test"
hideScore: true
id: "60ded6668734e65c51f50996"
language: "English"
maxLevel1: 10.47195
maxLevel2: 2.065616666666668
maxScore: 23400
name: "game test"
nbrDoors: 8
nbrPlayersPerTeam: 8
partner: "khouloud ben khssib"
playtime: 30
started: true
startedAt: "Fri, 02 Jul 2021 09:04:25 GMT"
startsAt: "Fri, 02 Jul 2021 09:03:00 GMT"
teams: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
teamsCount: 20
textColor: "#ffffff"
updatedAt: "2021-08-20T15:35:37.348Z"
user: "609321b935e3f04d04d44337"
__v: 0
_id: "60ded6668734e65c51f50996"
```

i have three array named as gametype

```
NumberofLive: any[] =[];
  NumberofTest: any[] =[];
  NumberofDemo: any[] =[];
```

i want every time to fill a table i wrote something like thiss

```
for(let i=0;i<this.MyGames.length; i++){
      
      switch(this.MyGames[i].gameType) { 
        case 'test': { 
        
          this.NumberofTest=this.NumberofTest+this.MyGames[i]           
           break; 
        } 
        case 'live': {                  

                          this.NumberofLive=this.NumberofLive+this.MyGames[i]           

           console.log('salzem');     console.log(this.NumberofLive[1].gameType)

           
           break; 
        } 
        default: {              


          this.NumberofDemo=this.NumberofDemo+this.MyGames[i]           
           break; 
        } 
     } 

    }
```

when i log my table i find something undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, please have a look below

```
for(let i=0;i<this.MyGames.length; i++){   
  switch(this.MyGames[i].gameType) { 

    case 'test':  
         this.NumberofTest.push(this.MyGames[i]);           
         break; 
         
    case 'live':                
         this.NumberofLive.push(this.MyGames[i]);   
         break; 
         
    default:             
         this.NumberofDemo.push(this.MyGames[i]);
  }  
}
```

**Another Solution**

```
this.NumberofTest = this.MyGames.filter((item) => item.gameType === 'test');
this.NumberofLive = this.MyGames.filter((item) => item.gameType === 'live');
this.NumberofDemo = this.MyGames.filter((item) => item.gameType !== 'test' && item.gameType !== 'live');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant just add up to array with "+" sign, you have to push new object into it.

```
this.NumberofTest.push(this.MyGames[i])
```

Also, I think a more elegant solution would be array.filter method without for loop as below:

```
this.NumberofTest = this.MyGames.filter((item) => item.gameType==='test')
```